# iPhone application compatibility

Tags: iphone

Please how can I make sure before developing my iPhone app that it will be compatible with iPhone4, 3GS, iPod touch and 3G?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the app keeping in mind all the features available in lowest version of iPhone you need it to be compatible to.

**For Example:**

Suppose you want it to be compatible to iPhone 2G then you cannot use **in-app SMS** feature as **iPhone 2G** cannot be upgraded to iOS 4.0 or higher.

In-app SMS feature is only available in iOS 4.0 and higher versions.

Hope this example gave you a proper idea.

Once the app is made, you should test your app throughly on different devices i.e. iPhone 3G, iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4 and iPod Touch.

Unless you test it on device, you cannot be sure because sometimes some of the things work in simulator but crashes on device.

So better to test on device.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Where can I find a full (or more comprehensive) list of features that can run on the different versions of iOS? You mentioned in-app SMS, but where can I find if there are any others?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the SDK you are talking about, you might want to make sure it runs on iOS 3.X versions. [See here for more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#Overview).

If it's the hardware you are talking about, you will need to test your app on separate pieces of hardware to make sure that they all run.

Comment: my boss told me that there is settings in xcode something like that to set to make sure your futur app will run on the different pieces i have mentioned..is that true ??

Comment: I think he might be talking about the SDK selection for your app. You can go into project info, and search for SDK, it should allow you to select which SDK you want to use for developing your app. However the selection might be limited, depending on which Xcode version you have, not sure if Xcode 4 supports really old SDKs, might want to stick with Xcode 3.

Comment: You should be using the latest SDK and set `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

Answer (score 1):

The settings in XCode that you make regarding which version of iOS your app will be compatible with is the iOS deployment target and the Base SDK. The Base SDK is the default version you are building against (this should be set to the most recent SDK which is currently 4.3). The iOS deployment target is the earliest version you would like your app to be available for (currently goes back to 3.0 on XCode 4).

These settings are in the settings for your target.

As for if your app will actually work on all of these devices depends on how you program for them. In other words, if you are using new APIs, they obviously will not work on versions that did not implement them.

Hope this helps.

Jamie

Answer (score 1):

You can't be sure without testing.  (and even with testing, some say...)

There are potential "gothcha's" in the iOS API documentation, in the Simulator handling of those APIs, and particularly in device performance, which you may not realize or be able to guess until you actually try an app out on all the device models and iOS versions which you plan to support.

Even some simple apps with no undocumented API use and no compiler or analyzer warnings, et.al., have been know to "break" after a new OS version is released.

You can "claim" an app is compatible by appropriate setting of the Deployment Target in the Build settings, lack of plist hardware restrictions, and in the app store submission data.  But that's only a claim, not compatibility.